# How to sort a table column numerically and alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, html, sorttable.js

I have been using [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js) to sort the tables on my webpage and it works for the most part, my only problem is that I am trying to sort servers which contain letters and numbers. Sorting alphabetically seemed like the best case to go with but it resulted in a small problem whenever I reached a value > 100.

The output would read 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,100,101,11,12,13,14,15,...,99

Of course it would be much better if I could get this with 100 after 99 so I changed that column to be sorted numerically and it worked for the most part. My final issue is that now I am having servers with similar names be separated from each other e.g: testServer1, Server1, testServer2, Server2,.... testServer99, Server99

**Images of output:**

[image][image]

As you can see, particularly on the left, like named hosts are not linked together as the numbers are what it is being sorted by.

**Links to sorttable.js:**

http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js
http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

---

**Demo is too long, here it he html, javascript linked above.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!script to make table sortable>
        <script src="sorttable.js"></script>

        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
        <title>Title</title>
        <style>
            body   {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
            h1, h2 {
               color:darkblue; 
               margin-bottom: 2px;
            }
            .good  {background-color: green;}
            .bad   {background-color: red;}
            .error {background-color: purple;}
            .resultTable, td, th {
               padding-left: 10px;
               padding-right: 10px;
               border-collapse: collapse;
               border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .resultTable th {
               background-color: darkblue;
               color: white;
            }
            .resultTable td {
               max-width: 110px;
               text-overflow: ellipsis;
               overflow: hidden;
               white-space: nowrap;
            }
            .resultTable td:active {
                background-color: #ffff99;
                max-width: 900px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="top">Header</h1>
        ---<br><br>
        <a href="#hypervisors">HyperVisors</a><br>
        <a href="#hosts">Hosts</a><br>

        <h2 id="hypervisors">HyperVisors</h2>
        <table class="resultTable" id="hypervisorTable">
          <!-- Table Header -->
          <tr>
            <th class=""sorttable_numeric">Host</th>
               <th>ql2xmaxqdepth</th>
               <th>ql2xloginretrycount</th>
               <th>qlport_down_retry</th>
               <th>VMware_version</th>
               <th>HBA</th>
               <th>Firmware_Version</th>
               <th>Driver_Version</th>
          </tr>

          <!-- Values  lentgh=26 first (hv%.int) -->
            <tr>
               <td>hv1.int</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
               <td>hv2.int</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
               <td>hv3.int</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
               <td>hv4.int</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
            </tr> 

            <tr>
               <td>hv5.int</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
                  <td >n/a</td>
            </tr> 

          <!-- Values  lentgh>=27 first (hv%.int) -->
        </table>
        <a href="#top">Top</a><br>

        <h2 id="hosts">Hosts</h2>
        <table class="resultTable" id="hostTable">
          <!-- Table Header -->
          <tr>
            <th class="sorttable_numeric">Host</th>
               <th>kernel</th>
               <th>num_cpu</th>
               <th>memory</th>
               <th>selinux</th>
               <th>packages</th>
               <th>openssl</th>
               <th>bash</th>
               <th>irqbalance</th>
               <th>interface</th>
               <th>grub_etc_ls</th>
               <th>grub_boot_ls</th>
               <th>grub_etc_md5</th>
               <th>grub_boot_md5</th>
               <th>cpms</th>
               <th>pab</th>
               <th>cal</th>
               <th>loginproxy</th>
               <th>mediapreview</th>
               <th>svc-auditd</th>
               <th>svc-crond</th>
               <th>svc-network</th>
               <th>svc-nrpe</th>
               <th>svc-sshd</th>
               <th>svc-snmpd</th>
               <th>svc-rsyslog</th>
               <th>svc-irqbalance</th>
               <th>svc-monit</th>
               <th>svc-limsender</th>
               <th>SCSI_Timeout_sda</th>
               <th>SCSI_Timeout_sdb</th>
               <th>SCSI_Timeout_sdc</th>
               <th>SCSI_Timeout_sdd</th>
               <th>SCSI_Timeout_sde</th>
          </tr>

          <!-- Values -->
          <tr>
             <td>ansible01</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>appsproxy01</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>appsproxy02</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>be01</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>be02</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>be03</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>be04</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>be99</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>be107</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>be100</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>be101</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>deployment01</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>dsaloc1-01</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>dsaloc1-02</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >Not verified</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
                <td >n/a</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <a href="#top">Top</a><br>

        <p>
           Words <i>Name</i>&#0153;<br>
           &copy; ----
        </p>

        <script>
            var sortHyper = document.getElementById("hypervisorTable");
            var sortHost = document.getElementById("hostTable");

            sorttable.makeSortable(sortHyper);
            sorttable.makeSortable(sortHost);
        </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: You are dealing with specific problem but there are no demo in the question. There are not many people who would want to set up a demo for experimenting in order to help you. So if you really want someone to help you, you need to make it easy and convenient. Otherwise changes that you get good answer are low.

Comment: You are correct, I'll put a demo up in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was available in the link you shared

Using custom sort keys

You may have some data which does go in an order but isn't identified by sorttable. The way to fix this problem is to use custom sort keys. Take, for example, a column of spelled out numbers. Ordinarily, sorttable wouldn't work here; it will treat the spelled-out numbers as strings, and so would sort the numbers in alphabetical order, i.e., five, four, one, three, two. To get around this, you can specify on a cell in your table a sorttable_customkey attribute, and sorttable will use the contents of that attribute instead of the text in the cell itself when sorting the table. So, for example, your table might look like this:

```
<table class="sortable">
<tr><th>Number (spelled)</th><th>Person</th></tr>
<tr><td sorttable_customkey="2">two</td><td>Jan</td></tr>
<tr><td sorttable_customkey="3">three</td><td>Bruce</td></tr>
<tr><td sorttable_customkey="1">one</td><td>Steve</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My table is built up from a  .yaml file of servers, although this is a possible solution in the sense of robustness It would be much greater if I had some way of sorting the table just using the the cell's value.

Comment: as per the documentation there is no other solution. You have to find any other plug in to suit your requirement like data tables, jplist etc

Comment: I was worried this may be the way, I have been thinking all morning on how to weigh up the values, I may give the customkeys another look and see If I can implement them dynamically.

Comment: ended up getting it work this way, sorttable_customkey="hv0004"
 This means I did a split of the characters and numbers and all number now have 4 digits with leading zero.. so the "alpha-sorting" works and be12 is before be100

Answer (score 0):

```
# Custom filter to enable a proper sorting by hostnames by padding zeros.
def hostname_padding(env,host):
    hostname = host.split(".",1)[0]

    # All NON-Digits, only taking first which fits our purpose
    try:
        hostname_padded = re.findall(r"([\D.]*\D+)", hostname)[0]
    except:
        hostname_padded = ""

    # All Digits - results is a string, padding to 4 digits
    hostnameDigits = re.findall(r"([\d.]*\d+)", hostname)
    for element in hostnameDigits:
        hostname_padded+=element.zfill(4)

    return hostname_padded
```

**This is the python script which creates the custom key**

```
            <table class="resultTable sortable">
          <!-- Table Header -->
          <tr>
            <th id="hostname">Host</th>
            {%- for category in categories %}
               <th>{{ category }}</th>
            {%- endfor %}
          </tr>

          <!-- Values, presorted -->
          {%- for host in results|sort %}
          <tr>
             <td sorttable_customkey="{{ host|hostname_padding }}">{{ host }}</td>
             {%- for category in categories %}
                <td {% if results[host][category][1] == "OK"  %}class=good{% endif %}{% if results[host][category][1] == "NOK"  %}class=bad{% endif %}{% if results[host][category][1] == "ERROR"  %}class=error{% endif %}>{{ results[host][category][0] }}</td>
             {%- endfor %}
          </tr> 
          {%- endfor %}
        </table>
```

**This is the HTML that it will fill up**

This answer was supplied by a friend of mine, I take no credit in the solution.

It is only posted to help others who may encounter a similar problem.